# where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

I have run into a problem when I have tried to select data from more than 1 table and I was wondering if anyone could help me. The tables are linked and I'm trying to select only things with a certain id. I have had success with queries with 1 table but with 2 tables it kicked an error my way:

> Query to get data from Recipe failed: Column `Recipe_ID` in where clause is ambiguous.

Here is my query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Recipe, Ingredients_Needed WHERE Recipe_ID ='$chosen_id'";
```

Comment: off topic, but make sure your `$chose_id` variable is properly escaped, otherwise you will be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does Recipe_ID appear in both Recipe and Ingredients_Needed?
IF it does then you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe, Ingredients_Needed WHERE Recipe.Recipe_ID = ....
```

As a side note, use correct join syntax not an implicit join ie:

```
SELECT r.*, n.*
FROM Recipe r 
INNER JOIN Ingredients_Needed n ON n.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
WHERE r.Recipe_ID = ...
```

This will make it clearer especially if you are joining on multiple tables with different conditions etc as you can see the aliased tables quickly just by looking at the query instead of guessing.

Comment: I'd suggest this change too: `SELECT Recipe.*, Ingredients_Needed.* `

Answer (score 0):

Specify the table:

```
WHERE table.Recipe_ID=
```

Answer (score 0):

specify which table receipe_id refere to: Recipe and/or Ingredients_Needed

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe r, Ingredients_Needed i WHERE r.Recipe_ID = x and r.Recipe_ID = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name your tables with aliases and specify relation. You probably have same column name in both tables or in table `Ingredients_Needed` column `Recipe_ID` have multiple same entries. So your SQL will be:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe R 
LEFT JOIN Ingredients_Needed I on R.ID=I.Recipe_ID 
WHERE R.ID = '$choden_id'
```

If you in table `Recipe` haven't `ID` but have `Recipe_ID`, just change `R.ID` for `R.Recipe_ID`

Comment: with this SQL you can get Recipies without Ingredients_Needed.
If you use only `INNER JOIN` you get only rows, where exists Ingredients_Needed